# Change stacked bar order when aesthetic fill is based on the interaction of two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to switch the stacked bar order when the aesthetic fill is based on the interaction of two factors. I tried to use `order = desc()` but it doesn't work. Below an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

country     <- rep(c('SE', 'FR', 'BE'), each = 2)
rain_fall   <- rep(c('winter to spring', 'summer'), 3)
amount_rain <- c(100, 10, 95, 5, 70, 2)
order       <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)

DT <- data.table(country, rain_fall, amount_rain, order)
DT[, ':='(country = factor(country), rain_fall = factor(rain_fall))]


plot_stacked <- ggplot(DT, aes(x     = reorder(country, - order), 
                               y     = amount_rain, 
                               fill  = interaction(country, rain_fall)) +
                   #I tried adding here  order = desc(interaction(country, rain_fall)))) + 
                 geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Does anyone know how I can still change the stacked order such that the summer bar is at the bottom? In the example below the summer bars are at the top (the thin ones). I would like them at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be hard because the stacking is based on the y axis. Unless you change the y axis  by some transformation or `unstack` the bars, I cannot in my naive opinion see how you could achieve what you would like to do. Perhaps set position to `dodge`(unstacks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column "rainfall" is a factor column, the values are plot in order. The default is in alphabetical order.  To change the plotting order, you need to specify the order of the factors.

In this problem adding `levels=c('winter to spring', 'summer')` to factor definition will change from alphabetical to the desired order.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

country     <- rep(c('SE', 'FR', 'BE'), each = 2)
rain_fall   <- rep(c('winter to spring', 'summer'), 3)
amount_rain <- c(100, 10, 95, 5, 70, 2)
order       <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)

DT <- data.table(country, rain_fall, amount_rain, order)
DT[, ':='(country = factor(country), rain_fall = factor(rain_fall, levels=c('winter to spring', 'summer')))]


plot_stacked <- ggplot(DT, aes(x = reorder(country, - order), 
                               y   = amount_rain, fill = interaction(country, rain_fall)) )+
                         geom_bar(stat = "identity")
print(plot_stacked)
```

[image]