How to change order of one variable in ggplot2
I need to make a grouped bar chart:
  pivot_longer(cols = c(2:5), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample_2, y = value, fill = name))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

I have this data set (csv format):
fH 40k,2.0005,2.0485,1.203,1.39525
fH 80k,1.379,1.50225,0.831,0.96325
fH 160k,0.92775,1.06125,0.5705,0.64425
fH 320k,0.7185,0.718,0.44025,0.48225
fH 640k,0.615,0.5325,0.43425,0.387
fH 1280k,0.56275,0.4285,0.3545,0.34925
fH 2560k,0.56825,0.424,0.307,0.32875
blank,0.55175,0.42975,0.3365,0.314
FP 10k,1.984,2.05375,1.217,1.26425
VP 10k,2.29,2.308,1.37375,1.39425

The plot I get has a disordered x-axis
What I need is to have it in the order as the data are provided. I tried to mutate the "sample_ID", but it gave me an error, I think because I have all the samples names 4x after long-pivoting.


Try aes(x = forcats::fct_inorder(sample_2) ......

The key is to make your variable a factor in the correct order.  There are many examples of how to order the x-axis in a plot. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728103/change-stacked-bar-order-when-aesthetic-fill-is-based-on-the-interaction-of-two/57729892#57729892
